Resources for Integrating Good Machine Learning Techniques (CoursEra preferred)
I've plateaued as a Python programmer.  I understand the ins and outs of developing:

Cross Validated ML Scripts for a variety of models (Random Forest, SVM, SVR, ...)
Multivariate tools (Lasso, Elastic Net, Ridge, logistic regression, clustering, ...)
Imputation (MICE, MissForest, KNN, ...)
Ways to handle categoric variables (OneHotEncoding, Frequency Encoding, ...)
Statistical transforms (min-max, normal standardization, ...)

However, I can't find an online class, or other reference on the Internet, that shows me how to integrate these tools.  Does anyone have any recommendation?
My question differs from Apoorva's Machine Learning resources, in that I'm looking specifically how to integrate these tools at an intermediate level.
I've had good luck learning through CourseEra. I guess any recommendation on this platform would be the easiest for me to follow up on.

This notebook goes through a long structured example, integrating concepts for the task of house price prediction.
The other notebooks on that page also have exercises and solutions at the end of each notebook. The first set of notebooks is sklearn-focused, whereas the second set focuses on neural nets and their tooling.
This github has some shorter examples. See the ML-focused sklearn notebooks in section 5 especially.
